# Memory leaks in apple frameworks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

When i release my class, i receive leaks with NSStrings. But i have only 2 NSString in properties. Other NSString I use in my methods in this class, and i release them before exit from the method.

```
[somestring release],somestring = nil;
```

Here is screenshot

[image]

Is it my problem? Or this leaks belongs to apple frameworks? I also use ASIHTTPRequest in my class.

**EDIT:** I found the problem. I used few times NSMutableArray and mutableCopy method, without autoreleasing.

**Before, and with leaks**: someMutableArray = [anotherClass.anotherMutableArray mutableCopy];

**After, and without leaks**: someMutableArray = [[anotherClass.anotherMutableArray mutableCopy]autoreleasing];

Answer (score 3):

Apple's frameworks are probably not leaking.

If you pass that variable to another object and **that other object** retains it without releasing, you'll see a leak. And it'll appear to be where you allocated the string, rather than in the second object.

Memory leaks are why I gave up on ASIHTTPRequest. I knew enough to know it was coming from ASIHTTPRequest, but wasn't able to find out where.

Probably the best thing you can do in this case is look at the block history for one of the leaked blocks. You'll see various retains and releases. They should balance; more, each retain should have a release it its counterpart. For instance, if you see a retain of an object in an object setter, you should verify that the previous object was released in that setter and there's a release in the dealloc. Try to identify the highest level object that's leaking, as the other leaks are probably member variables of it.

Answer (score 2):

In instruments, there's a section named Call Tree at the left hand side. When you check Hide System Libraries, then only your method calls show up. You should try this to see if your own code has anything to do with the leaks.

Comment: @TimurMustafaev It is quite possible that it is not SBJson either, rather your code retains and then does not release the objects you get from the SBJson framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to release the variables in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Then make sure you are assigning values to properties and not the variables. Use self.somestring = "value" instead of just somestring = "value".